# Postgres Compress data on server side and decompress on client side

Tags: postgresql, compression

Is there some mechanism in Postgres that allows to compress data on server side before sending it to the client and then decompress it on client side to save the time needed to send large amount of data through slow connection?

Answer (score 0):

[libpq documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-connect.html) states that there is a parameter `sslcompression` which when enabled will allow the data stream to be compressed. This requires compatible OpenSSL libraries to be used and of course SSL to be enabled.

Depending on how you're connecting to the server it might be an option. But there is currently no compression in the actual protocol itself. You would have to use a separate compressing tunneling to achieve that.